# JavaScript Beginner - Need to check first two digits of a zip code

Tags: javascript, validation

Need to write a script that checks the first two digits of a zip code, if it matches on form submission, kick back an error message. Namely:

alaska = 99
hawaii = 96
PR = 00

(customer is not using a state dropdown) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm exremely new to javascript and have never worked with strings before. I'm not even sure where to start with how to write the function. Basically I just need some direction on getting started on it since it involves strings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functions match() or substring(), for match() you will need to know [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

[w3schools javascript string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)